# What's the connection with Back to the Future movie?

Tags: plot-explanation, back-to-the-future, a-million-ways-to-die-in-the-west

In the movie 'A Million Ways to Die in the West' [Dr. Emmett "Doc" Brown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emmett_Brown) from 'Back to the Future' [appears in one of the scene](https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=W922yFkpFNU#t=25) with his time machine.
What is the connection with that old movie?

Comment: Huh? What connection? A joke maybe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just a cameo which only raised a bit of inconsistency.

> This film takes place in 1882 and is inconsistent with the Back To The
>   Future timeline, which places Doc in the west during 1885 and
>   later.(Source: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emmett_Brown#In_other_media))

Answer (score 1):

Back to the future was(is) a very popular movie, there is no real importance or connection except to give you a few kicks